# 2013 CQWP with tables and multiple link

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part

I have an Item Style I created that displays items in more of a table list format rather than a linear one. I am also trying to display the Title link for the item as well as link  for a hyperlink field. I am trying to display its title instead of the full url. XSLT is not my strong suit I appreciate your patience and assistance. Below is the section of the XSLT performing the formatting.

```
<td class="ms-vb2">
    <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" title="{@LinkToolTip}">                  <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
    </a>
  </td>
  <td>
<div class="description">
    <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" title="{@LinkToolTip}">   <xsl:value-of select="@(Internal Field Name)"/>
</a>
     </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@LinkUrl` instead of `$SafeLinkUrl`.

Comment: That bombs out the ItemStyle altogether.

Comment: So I've got this close to what I want since each link has the same display text I am taking a rather inelegant route but effective for my needs. I just need to express the xsl:value-of select in a hidden fashion. I use the Action slot to populate the URL but if I could just hide the url in the output (without a CSS preferably) then that would be ideal. I can capture the value-of as a variable it seems.
            <

a href="{@Action}" title="{@LinkToolTip}">Request this Action<xsl:value-of select="@Action"/>